# Building & running C program in Eclipse Juno in 12.04

Tags: eclipse, c

I have recently installed Ubuntu and Eclipse to compile a library (written by someone else). I am familiar with C and thus I added all the relevant header files in a a folder and added the path to that folder in the `project>properties>paths>GNU C`. 
In the `src` folder I have a `.c` file with the main function and several `.c` files provided in the package which are called in the main `.c` file (not named  but ).

This is the output after I build the project (using toolchain Linux GCC and GNU builder):

```
15:43:57 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project Delaunay_test ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/detri.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0      -MMD -MP -MF"src/detri.d" -MT"src/detri.d" -o "src/detri.o" "../src/detri.c"
In file included from /media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/trist.h:8:0,
             from /media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/dt.h:8,
             from /media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/detri.h:5,
             from ../src/detri.c:41:/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/basic.h:65:8: error: conflicting types     for ‘bzero’

/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/basic.h:66:8: error: conflicting types     for ‘bcopy’
/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/basic.h:100:0: warning: "HIBITS"        redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/values.h:48:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/basic.h:102:0: warning: "HIBITL"     redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/values.h:49:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/media/HDD/Programming/C/Detri_2.6.a/Headers/basic.h:204:0: warning: "powerof2"          redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/param.h:72:0: note: this is the location of the     previous definition
../src/detri.c:110:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
make: *** [src/detri.o] Error 1

15:43:58 Build Finished (took 328ms)
```

If i change the toolchain to mingw or something else, its states that it is unsupported on this system but builds anyway.

When the build is done, running it yields the following error message:

```
Binary not found
```

Any help is appreciated.